# I can't use findViewById(int). Reference is not possible

Tags: android, kotlin

I just need to be able to use findViewById(int). I've seen several examples. But I couldn't understand it because it was a little different from me.

I need to know the true value of the checkbox in the notification, and to do that I have to use findViewById(int).
Please help me how can i fix the code so i can reference the checkbox.

The error only occurs with findViewById(int).

Here's the code:

```
companion object {
    const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 100
    const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1000"

}

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    createNotificationChannel(context)
    notifyNotification(context)

}

private fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
            NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
            "기상 알람",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )

        NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)


    }
}

private fun notifyNotification(context: Context) {

    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {

        val build = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("알람")
            .setContentText("일어날 시간입니다.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)


        notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, build.build())

        val firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.reference

        val cb1 = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)
        if (cb1.isChecked == true) {
            databaseReference.child("c").setValue("C")

        }
    }

 }
```

Can't use requireView

```
val cb = requireView().findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkbox)

        if (cb.ischecked == true)
```

Comment: If this is in a Fragment instead of an Activity, use `requireView().findViewById…`. The function you’re calling is used to search for a view within some view group. When you see it called without the view group, that’s because the Activity class has a shortcut that lets you call the function directly and it automatically calls it on the root view of the current layout for you. Fragment doesn’t have this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the layout's elements outside the activity, or without a reference to the activity which inflated the layout. You could define a constant value somewhere in your application:

```
object Constants{
  var checked = false
}
```

and update it on the onChecked event of the checkbox. Then you can access the checked variable in your notification code:

```
if(Constants.checked){
  databaseReference.child("c").setValue("C")
}
```

Edit, thanks to user [tenfour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506796/tenfour04) for reminding me:

You can also access the elements of a view, when you have a reference to the root view of the layout.

```
view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkbox).isChecked
```

Comment: This is false. You can access the layout’s elements if you have a reference to the root view of the layout.

Comment: I think using it in broadcast is the problem.

It is not possible to get the view currently on the screen as a context with findViewById.

 We are looking for a way to add parameters to a function that creates a notification and use it.

Comment: I've attached what I coded as you advised. Can't use requireView or view

Comment: And did you try to use a singleton object with a boolean in it, like my first example? This might do the trick.